# How to choose a random input from 7 given input?

Tags: python

I'm creating a lottery hack machine which gets the winning numbers of the last 7 days and tries to select a winner from the the 7 and shuffle the numbers of that selection and print the result. All this occurs at random.

```
#lottery hack

print "WELCOME TO LOTTERY HACK MACHINE!!!\n"
today = int(raw_input( "Please enter today's date: " ))
if today<=31:
    print "Please enter the 4-digit prize winning lottery number for the last 7 days"
    y = raw_input( "Enter 7 numbers separated by commas: " )
    input_list = y.split(',')
    numbers = [float(x.strip()) for x in input_list]

elif today>31:
    print "A month has only 31 days ;P"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) function for this. It returns a random element from the sequence you pass it.

```
import random
print "WELCOME TO LOTTERY HACK MACHINE!!!\n"
today = int(raw_input( "Please enter today's date: " ))
if today<=31:
    print "Please enter the 4-digit prize winning lottery number for the last 7 days"
    y = raw_input( "Enter 7 numbers separated by commas: " )
    input_list = y.split(',')
    numbers = [float(x.strip()) for x in input_list]
    print random.choice(numbers)

elif today>31:
    print "A month has only 31 days ;P"
```

If you want to shuffle the entire list in place instead of printing random elements from it one at a time, you can use the [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function.

```
import random
print "WELCOME TO LOTTERY HACK MACHINE!!!\n"
today = int(raw_input( "Please enter today's date: " ))
if today<=31:
    print "Please enter the 4-digit prize winning lottery number for the last 7 days"
    y = raw_input( "Enter 7 numbers separated by commas: " )
    input_list = y.split(',')
    numbers = [float(x.strip()) for x in input_list]
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    print numbers

elif today>31:
    print "A month has only 31 days ;P"
```

As clarified in the comments, you need an approach that combines these two approaches.

```
import random
print "WELCOME TO LOTTERY HACK MACHINE!!!\n"
today = int(raw_input( "Please enter today's date: " ))
if today<=31:
    print "Please enter the 4-digit prize winning lottery number for the last 7 days"
    y = raw_input( "Enter 7 numbers separated by commas: " )
    input_list = y.split(',')
    numbers = [list(x.strip()) for x in input_list]
    choice = random.choice(numbers)
    random.shuffle(choice)
    print ''.join(choice)

elif today>31:
    print "A month has only 31 days ;P"
```

Comment: i need to shuffle the number of the randomly chosen integer

Comment: @user5476178 Do you want to shuffle the entire list and then print it out?

Comment: @user5476178 I don't know what you need then. Can you edit your post to add example input and output.

Comment: i wanna create a python program which receives 7 inputs in one go and then select a random input from that and then shuffle the four digits of that selected number and finally print that answer

Comment: @user5476178 I just added something that should work for you.

Comment: @user5476178 Great, glad I could help! In that case, if you could accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer), that would be awesome! That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives me credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) for random.
Here's how you could use it :

```
import random
print(random.choice(numbers))
```

The `choice` method does the job for you of getting a random element from a sequence